# Is it possible to migrate to HelixToolKit.WPF.SharpDX from HelixToolKit.WPF in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

I have written a significant part of my codes in C# using HelixToolKit.WPF, but its performance is not satisfied. Thus, I decide to change it to HelixToolKit.WPF.SharpDX library and use the power of DirectX 11 to enhance its performance. In this Situation, many parts of the code are classes which have been inherited from the old component and objects in the first library. Is it a way to use the old classes with minor changes instead of changing all parts of the code? Generally speaking, are these library entirely different in their components?

Answer (score 2):

If your project only renders static mesh, you won't get significant benefits from SharpDX version. However, if your project needs to render many lines/points/billboards etc, or needs advanced feature such as bone skinning, instancing, it will be worth converting to the SharpDX version.

Although SharpDX version trys to implement similar to the WPF version, but the scene graph is significant different from the WPF version. If your project doing a lot of inheritance from model classes, you won't be able to convert directly.

I would recommend to rewrite and separate geometry from models and avoid model inheritances.